# how rails override the middleware method defined by rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

This question is about rails source code.

I notice **middleware** method definded in *railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb* (**Rails**)

```
def middleware
  middlewares = []
  middlewares << [Rails::Rack::Debugger] if options[:debugger]
  middlewares << [::Rack::ContentLength]
  Hash.new(middlewares)
end
```

**I think it returns a blank hash {}**. It overrides the method with same name which definded in 
*lib/rack/server.rb*

If I traced right, this method called by **build_app** which definded in *lib/rack/server.rb* (**Rack**)

```
def build_app(app)
  middleware[options[:environment]].reverse_each do |middleware|
    middleware = middleware.call(self) if middleware.respond_to?(:call)
    next unless middleware
    klass, *args = middleware
    app = klass.new(app, *args)
  end
  app
end
```

My question is: **How does the middleware method works?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method does not just return a blank hash, despite appearances. The [`Hash.new` constructor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) takes the argument and makes that the default value returned if the specified key is missing. Example:

```
h=Hash.new([1])
h[:missing_key]
=> [1]
```

The `build_app` method is calling `middleware[options[:environment]]`. so if the specified environment doesn't exist, it will at least get back a minimal set of middleware.